# Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Tags: php, pdf-form

I'm using fpdf in creating pdf in php and I'm getting this error when running:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp1\htdocs\arvin2\public\pdf2\id.php on line 3
FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file
```

This is my php code (report.php):

```
<form action="http://localhost/pdf2/id.php" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="text" name="id">
<input type="submit" name="submitpdf" value="Print"/>
</form>
```

the other one(eto.php):

```
<?php
require('mysql_table.php');
$id=$_POST['id'];

class PDF extends PDF_MySQL_Table
{
function Header()
{
//Title
$this->SetFont('Arial','',18);
$this->Cell(0,6,'Type of Leave',0,1,'C');
$this->Ln(10);
//Ensure table header is output
parent::Header();
}
}

mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('auth');


$pdf=new PDF();
//First table: put all columns automatically
$pdf->AddPage();
//Second table: specify 3 columns
$pdf->AddCol('leave_id',20,'','C');
$pdf->AddCol('fullname',40,'Fullname');
$pdf->AddCol('type_of_leave',40,'Type of Leave','R');
$prop=array('HeaderColor'=>array(255,150,100),
        'color1'=>array(210,245,255),
        'color2'=>array(255,255,210),
        'padding'=>2);
$pdf->Table('select leave_id, fullname, type_of_leave from application where     id_no="$_POST[id]"',$prop);
$pdf->Output();

?>
```

When I put:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitpdf']))
{
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    //your code goes here
}
```

The error says:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$pdf' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp1\htdocs\arvin2\public\pdf2\id.php on line 34
```

The output should be all the info of ID numbers inputted in the text field  printed in the pdf form.

Comment: For the "some data has already been output", you should make sure there aren't any extra (whitespace?) characters surrounding the `<?php ... ?>` code. For the undefined index, looks like your `id` form field always stays empty.

Comment: watch out SQL Injection.

Comment: The "extra output" is the error message, so by removing the ID issue the other will succeed as well

Comment: there were no white spaces sir..

Comment: @AndréDaniel yes its always stays empty how could I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put if isset on your code. ie

```
if(isset($_POST['submitpdf']))
{
//$id=$_POST['id'];
//your code goes here
}
```

this is to ensure that your code would only run after reading your form-data

EDIT:

your new error i guess comes from the select string.

```
$pdf->Table('select leave_id, fullname, type_of_leave from application where     id_no="$_POST[id]"',$prop);
```

change it to this:

```
$pdf->Table("select leave_id, fullname, type_of_leave from application where id_no=".$_POST[id],$prop);
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp1\htdocs\arvin2\public\pdf2\id.php on line 29

Comment: No they were not in the same file

Comment: sir now it says: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$pdf' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp1\htdocs\arvin2\public\pdf2\id.php on line 30

Comment: could you please update your codes and question posted above? I couldn't visualize why it gives you an error.

check your  semi-colons and parentheses by the way

Comment: please try and apply neccessary changes.
like the if isset.
and the modified string for select. 
see if it would work. then update your question again

Comment: first, check if your database are populated(it has data to show). second is, try to run your sql code on a terminal(or at phpmyadmin) check if it does fetch data from the database.

Comment: sir it is populated and it does fetch data from the database

Comment: your code would be fine only for PHP syntax.
im not quite used to fpdf. check your fpdf syntax on how it calls on the database. or wait for the experts as of the moment :)

Comment: Be careful about SQL injection, this code is vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same error.

```
Data has already been sent to output, unable to output PDF file
```

This means before creating pdf with mPDF some data is stored in the buffer which is sended to the browser. Therefore it is unable to create PDF.

Just do this.. Add this below php built-in function at the first line of your page were you are preparing data for pdf.

```
op_start();
```

And add this below php built-in function before mPDF code (before where you are calling mpdf)

```
ob_end_flush();

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

So that it will clear all buffer output before processing mPDF.

Answer (score 0):

You should use before the data you want to output in pdf.

```
ob_start();
```

Then use ob_end_clean().

```
ob_end_clean();
$pdf->Output(time().'.pdf', 'D')
```

Answer (score -1):

**Error :** **Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file**

You can use 2 line code for fix this problem

1. You should write Top of the page

> ob_start()

2. Before your PDF Output Line **$pdf->Output();** to add new line

> ob_end_flush();
>
> $pdf->Output();

I think you may solve this problem & enjoy more!

> Thanks
>
> Md Salahuddin Khan
>
> [MegamindIT](http://megamindit.com)